# How can I change dialog position to show dialog?

Tags: flutter, dart, dialog, flutter-layout

Currently dialog show in center of the screen.
I want to show dialog just after the add icon.

[image]

Code :

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: ListTile(
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: () async {
              await showDialogOnButtonPress();
            },
          ),
          title: const Text("Title 1"),
        ) 
        );
    }
```

showDialogOnButtonPress() Function :

```
showDialogOnButtonPress() {
        showDialog(
            context: context,
            barrierDismissible: false,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return const Dialog(
                child: ListTile(
                  dense: true,
                  title: Text(
                    "Alert!",
                  ),
                ),
              );});}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Multiple Items I have so Its not work.

Answer (score 3):

Try below code set  `alignment: Alignment.topLeft,`:

```
showDialogOnButtonPress(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return const Dialog(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: ListTile(
              dense: true,
              title: Text(
                "Alert!",
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
```

Widget:

```
ListTile(
  leading: IconButton(
    icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
    onPressed: () async {
      await showDialogOnButtonPress(context);
    },
  ),
  title: const Text("Title 1"),
),
```

Result-> [image]

Comment: Thanks. Its fixed position. Multiple items are there. what if I want to show dialog after 5th item?

Answer (score 2):

You can align and position your dialog like this.

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  barrierDismissible: true,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return Dialog(
      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
      insetPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, top: 20),
      child: Container(
        width: 100,
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text("Alert!"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: Thanks. Its fixed position. Multiple items are there. what if I want to show dialog after 5th item?

Comment: if you want to show a widget after an item or a click position for example, you need to use Stack with positioned widget. and you can hide/show this widget where ever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I propose to you to use a visibility widget next to this widget and Change the State of visible to true whee it's successfully added.

Comment: Thankyou for the response. Do you have any example for how can I achieve it?

Comment: bool isVisible =false;
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: ListTile(
          leading:

          Stack(children:[IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: () async {
              // await showDialogOnButtonPress();
              setState((){isVisibile =true;});
            },
          ),
            Visibility(
                visible: isVisible,
                child:Container(child:Text("added"))),

          ]),


          title: const Text("Title 1"),
        )
    );
  }

Comment: when you use man items and you need to show this alert, you can declare a map and add the visibility option as boolean for each element: 
ex: List<Map<String, dynamic>> yourList = [{"element":"test", "isVisible":false}];

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `Overlay` instead of `Dialog`.

```
late OverlayEntry _popupDialog;

void _showPopupDialog(int titleIndex) {
  _popupDialog = _buildPopupDialog(titleIndex);
  Overlay.of(context)?.insert(_popupDialog);
}

void _dismissPopupDialog() {
  _popupDialog.remove();
}

OverlayEntry _buildPopupDialog(int index) {

  RenderBox renderBox = ...; // find the title, as the anchor view of popupDialog
  final size = renderBox.size;
  final offset = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);

  return OverlayEntry(
    builder: (context) => Positioned(
      left: offset.dx,
      top: offset.dy + size.height,
        child: Material( // make it seems like a dialog
          elevation: 8,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
          ),
          child: Container(
            width: ...,
            height: ...,
            child: ...,
           ),
      ),
    )
  );
}
```

And if your dialog will show a selectable list, `DropdownButton` with `DropdownMenuItem` is better.

Answer (score 0):

You can align and position your dialog widget like this.

```
showDialog(
       context: context,
       builder: (context) {
           return Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  child: Container(
                  width: 100,
                      child: ListTile(
                       title: Text("Alert!"),
                      ),
                   ),
                );
             });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Remember Dialog Widget is center aligned it is not meant to be customized.
2. Even if you want custom position then use stack and positioned widget to achieve the custom results.

```dart
// Replace Dialog widget with below code for custom result.
Stack(
   children: [
      Positioned(
         top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.50,
         child: => your ListTile widget goes here.
      ),
    ],
)
```

3. To answer the Remaining part of your question of how to give a dynamically changing position to the dialog as per the changing number of elements in the list -> This is very well explained here: [https://blog.logrocket.com/complete-guide-implementing-overlays-flutter/#:~:text=GitHub%20repository.-,Example%203%3A%20The%20Overlay%20widget%20follows%20while%20scrolling,-Similar%20to%20the](https://blog.logrocket.com/complete-guide-implementing-overlays-flutter/#:%7E:text=GitHub%20repository.-,Example%203%3A%20The%20Overlay%20widget%20follows%20while%20scrolling,-Similar%20to%20the)

[image: Output]