# How do I change the position of the alert dialog in top in Flutter, Align TopCenter does not work

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

i'm new in Flutter. How do I change the position of the alert dialog in top of Screen in Flutter, I've used align TopCenter but it doesn't work. is there a solution?

this is my code:

```
 body: Scaffold(
    body: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            ErrorAlert(context: context, message: "error message");
          },
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: appDimens.paddingw6),
            child: Text(
              "Show Dialog",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Color(0xffFF9900),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

This is ErrorAlert widget

```
    Future<dynamic> ErrorAlert({
  required BuildContext context,
  String? message,
}) {
  return showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0),
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (contex) {
        return Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          child: AlertDialog(
            backgroundColor: Color(0xffFFF4F2),
            elevation: 0,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0))),
            content: Container(
              height: 20,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 40,
              child: Row(
                // mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Image.asset(
                        "assets/icon/padlock.png",
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                      Text(message ?? "Error",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xffFC6762))),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Center(
                    child: IconButton(
                     ..........
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      });
}
```

this is the result:

[image]

Comment: refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71692788/13997210)

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `AlertDialog` from `ErrorAlert` function, dialog will be shown as you expected. As we know `AlertDialog` is a kind of Dialog. So we shouldn't use `AlertDialog` inside `showDialog` widget.

```
 Future<dynamic> ErrorAlert({
        required BuildContext context,
        String? message,
      }) {
        return showDialog(
            context: context,
            barrierColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0),
            barrierDismissible: false,
            builder: (contex) {
              return Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                child: Material(
                  child:  Container(
                      color: Color(0xffFFF4F2),
                      height: 20,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 40,
                      child: Row(
                        // mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            children: [
                                Icon(Icons.desktop_mac, color: Colors.blue,),
                              Text(message ?? "Error",
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xffFC6762))),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Center(
                            child: IconButton(onPressed: () {  }, icon: Icon(Icons.read_more),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
              );
            });
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `insetPadding` of `AlertDialog`, like this:

```
AlertDialog(
  insetPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 300),//<---- add this
  backgroundColor: Color(0xffFFF4F2),
  elevation: 0,
  ...
)
```

[image]

**Or** you can Wrap your `AlertDialog` with `Column` like this:

```
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    AlertDialog(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xffFFF4F2),
      elevation: 0,
      ...
    )
  ]
)
```

[image]

Comment: I think alerts can't always stay on top because they correspond to padding bottom. even though the screen is not always the same size. is there any other way to make alert always on top like appbar position.

Comment: I updated my answer, check it out. @Queen